# WinForms : recursive access control in control

Tags: c#, winforms, recursion

I try to make my WinForms app responsive. For that I use this [class](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1140717/A-Responsive-Design-Technique-for-WinForms#_articleTop). It's work fine if all my control are directly on my form but when I put control in control it's doesn't work because my function is not recursive and I don't know how to do that.

here is my code

```
foreach (Control Ctl in this.Controls)
{                    
    if (Ctl is PictureBox)
    {
        Ctl.Width = ResponsiveObj.GetMetrics(Ctl.Width, "Width");
        Ctl.Height = ResponsiveObj.GetMetrics(Ctl.Height, "Height");
        Ctl.Top = ResponsiveObj.GetMetrics(Ctl.Top, "Top");
        Ctl.Left = ResponsiveObj.GetMetrics(Ctl.Left, "Left");
    }
    else
    {
        Ctl.Font = new Font(FontFamily.GenericSansSerif, ResponsiveObj.GetMetrics((int)Ctl.Font.Size), FontStyle.Regular);
        Ctl.Width = ResponsiveObj.GetMetrics(Ctl.Width, "Width");
        Ctl.Height = ResponsiveObj.GetMetrics(Ctl.Height, "Height");
        Ctl.Top = ResponsiveObj.GetMetrics(Ctl.Top, "Top");
        Ctl.Left = ResponsiveObj.GetMetrics(Ctl.Left, "Left");
    }
}
```

I want to make this recursive to be sure I'm do the stuff on all control in my form. Please can someone help me to do this ?

Comment: You can try to do it, will help if you don't succes on your own.
First, create a method with parameters of type Control, and call your method inside your method when you need to.

Comment: This is one of the examples where c# 7's local functions would be great. You create a function that accepts no parameters and inside it create a recursive local function that accepts a control, starting with `this`.

Comment: thank you all I can't post my code in comment but is near the solution see in Ivan's link